# Can't show a layout and delete sms at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, sms, smsmanager

I would like to delete sms received from a phone number so quickly that it is not shown to the user (in order to "block" this phone number that spam the user). I also want my android app to show a layout but it seems to be impossible to do both at the same time!

This is my method to delete sms:

```
 public void deleteSMS(Context context, String number) {
    try {

        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                String address = c.getString(2);


                if (address.equals(number)) {

                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SMS deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Then, to block the phone number "123456", I do :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
int r = 0;
         while (r<1){
             deleteSMS(this, "123456");}
```

The app deletes sms perfectly, whenever I send one, but it doesn't show any layout or toasts. Also when I just do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     deleteSMS(this, "123456");
```

It shows all the layout, toasts, and delete the sms. Do you have an idea to fix it ?

Comment: `it show all the layout, toasts, and delete the sms` ... isn't that what you want it to do?

Comment: that's what i want but it works only when i delete sms once (in the second case) ! i want it to work when deleteSMS() is always restarted (like int the first case). Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: I am confused, why would you want to delete more than the message you received? If you delete a message when you receive it, and you don't have any other messages from that number, there shouldn't be any other messages to delete so I am not sure I understand the issue. Sorry :|

Comment: it has to delete ALL the sms that are received from someone. Since the app starts, all the sms received from this guy in the past or sms that will be received in the future (while the app is working) are deleted instantaneously. The second code "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     deleteSMS(this, "123456");" just delete the sms that were received in the past.

Comment: have deleteSMS return a boolean (true if it succeeds false if it doesnt) and break your while loop if it fails (while(r < 1){ if(!deleteSMS(this, "123456")) break; } Right now you have a never ending while loop (which I am surprised doesn't break your app) which is why the layout doesn't inflate.

Comment: yes this is the aim of my app, delete all the sms coming from a phone number. The action of "deleting sms" never has to stop because the user can receive other sms in the future. understanding ? :)

Comment: You aren't really doing this the way you are supposed to do it though. You should be deleting single messages as a time. It is a poor user experience to have something deleted that you don't explicitly delete. What if you want to stop getting messages from someone, but don't want to delete the messages you already have? Either way, you don't want a never ending loop in your app ESPECIALLY on the main thread.

Comment: do you have an idea to fix it ? to do the same in a different way ?

Comment: I mean if you really want to you can push your deleteSMS off to a thread, and have that thread continue running, but like I say this kind of goes against the convention of what you are trying to do. The idea with SMS is to receive the text when it comes in and delete it that way, this way your app is always going to be running/processing which isn't a great idea for what you are trying to do. You will have an app running 24/7 that may actually be doing something 30 seconds out of the day.

Comment: ok i will try to "push my deleteSMS off to a thread". I'm a newbie so i'm going to search how to do that. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a start since (after a number of comments) it seems you are intent on doing it where the app is always running)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private final static int SERVICE_ID = 1234;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DeleteSmsService.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notice = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Deleting SMS Messages")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notice);
    }
}
```

Then create a Service

```
public DeleteSmsService extends Service{

    private ContentResolver contentResolver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    deleteSms(contentResolver, "123456");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void deleteSMS(ContentResolver cr, String number) { 

        try {

            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor c = cr.query(uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    String address = c.getString(2);

                    if (address.equals(number)) {
                        cr.delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

I haven't tested any of this, I have no clue if there are errors in it or if formatting may be off as I just typed it up really quick. This is to get you started doing what you want to do the best way I can think of doing it without bogging down the UI thread and maintaining normal conventions. You may need to utilize a thread handler, not sure (again haven't tested it).

Again, I would not do it this way, but this is just to help get you started with what you are trying to do since this is what you seem intent on doing.